# How to convert 6/2/2000 to 06/02/2000 in C#

Tags: c#, date, format

I have a string coming from one place:

"06/02/2000"

I have another string coming from a different place:

"6/2/2000"

I need to compare these two to do some processing.

When comparing these two, it's different when it shouldn't be.

How can I change the second from "6/2/2000" to "06/02/2000"? this is currently a string.

I tried to do this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(data[i].contract_dt, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it's bombing because of "6/2/2000"

Comment: use `Parse` instead of `ParseExact`

Comment: ParseExact could receive an array of formats not just one format

Comment: `"6/2/2000"` is neither MM nor dd.  Exact means exactly as specified

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parse both dates using `M/d/yyyy` format and then compare the actual `DateTime` object.

The format `M/d/yyyy` will work for single and double digits day/month, so  it will work for both date strings.

See: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Thanks. I did as you said and was able to compare. I can accept your answer in 1 minute.